# How to access variable from a static method

Tags: java, variables, static

I want to access a `variable` from a `static` method.

For example :

```
public class ABC
{
    public static void ABC()
    {
        int abc = 123;
        int bcd = 234;
    }
    public int getabc()
    {
        int tempabc = abc;
        return tempabc;
    }
    public int getbcd()
     {
        int tempbcd = bcd;
        return tempbcd;
    }
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(ABC.getabc());
    }
}
```

So here's the error code :

```
error: cannot find symbol
        int tempabc = abc;
                      ^
symbol:   variable abc
location: class ABC

error: cannot find symbol
        int tempbcd = bcd;
                      ^
symbol:   variable bcd
location: class ABC

error: non-static method getabc() cannot be referenced from a static context
        System.out.println(ABC.getabc());
                              ^
3 errors
```

So, how can I access the `value` of the `variable` from a static method?

EDIT :

I have edited the code, and I just want to get the value of `abc` from the `static` `ABC()`. But based on the sample code above, it's show error when compiled.

The sample code is have the same style of the program code.

OK, here is my program code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadHighestScoreFile
{   
    public static void ReadHighestScoreFile() throws IOException
    {
        final int NAME_SIZE = 35;
        String name = "";
        public static String names = 0;
        static int hours, minutes, seconds, clicks;

        File file = new File("Highest.txt");
        RandomAccessFile out = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

        for (int i = 0; i < NAME_SIZE; i++)
        {
            name += out.readChar();
        }

        names = name;
        hours = out.readInt();
        minutes = out.readInt();
        seconds = out.readInt();
        clicks = out.readInt();

        System.out.println(">> Name : " + names);
        System.out.println(">> Hour : " + hours);
        System.out.println(">> Minute: " + minutes);
        System.out.println(">> Second : " + seconds);
        System.out.println(">> Click : " + clicks);     

        out.close();
    }
}
```

My program is used to access a file named `Highest.txt`. But I need to get the values of `names`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`, and `clicks` to implement to my main program. I found this problem when I tried to implement it to my main program.

If I doing it seperately, meaning that I create a `main` method for this code, it will work fine. But now I need to get these values for my main program to perform other operations.

Comment: Your `ABC()` method looks suspiciously like an attempt at a "static constructor", which doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: You're trying to access function-scope variables rather than static variables.

Comment: Try to read this first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: Are you sure you want your variables to be static?

Comment: I have edited my post, please have a look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posting has conflicting statements:

```
1. how to access variable from a static class?
```

Your code does not have a static class defined but a static method with same name as class ABC.

```
2. static method that has same name as class `ABC`.
```

If you are thinking that it is the way creating a static class, it is wrong. Static classes can only be inner to Outer classes.

```
3. tempabc = abc.
```

Even if you define a static class, accessing non static variables is not in this way. Unless the variable too is a static, you require to create an instance of the static class and access the variable value in an appropriate way.

**Answer to second part of your posting**:
You should define a class to encapsulate the said fields as defined below:

```
class HighestData {
    String names;  
    int hours;  
    int minutes;  
    int seconds;  
    int clicks;  

    // define setter, getter methods or a constructor with input params for above fields.
}
```

Change method from `void` to `return object of HighestData`.

```
public static HighestData ReadHighestScoreFile() throws IOException {  
    // your code here  
    // ...  
    HighestData data = new HighestData();  
    data.setName( name );  
    data.setHours( out.readInt() );  
    data.setMinutes( out.readInt() );  
    data.setSeconds( out.readInt() );  
    data.setClicks( out.readInt() );  
    // ...  
    return data;  
}
```

The caller of `ReadHighestScoreFile()` method can now have handle to `HighestData` object and use it to process further.

Lastly but important that, unlike in C, you can't define *local* static fields in Java. They must be at class level.

Comment: My fault, it's `method`, not `class`. I'm following the example from the reference book, but the book's example has `main` method.

Comment: @AnonyNewbie - My answer to your second part of posting should be helping solve your problem.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Any result I will comment here later. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like my code is calling the `class` instead of calling the `method`.

Answer (score 2):

`abc` is a method local variable. It can't be accessed outside that method.

Answer (score 2):

`abc` has local scope with respect to `ABC()`.  If you want it back, you could return an `int` from `ABC()` instead:

```
public static int ABC()
{
    int abc = 123;
    return abc;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(ABC());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare it in the class scope:

```
public static int abc = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a get that returns a String:

```
public static String getABC()
{
    string i = "abc";
    return i;
}
```

Then call that function:

```
System.out.println(getABC());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not a class variable but a method variable. Make sure you know what you are doing if you use static variable. It is often a bad idea to use them.
Here is how you can access a static variable.

```
public static class ABC {
  public static int someInt = 123;
}

public static class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ABC.someInt);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you really tried compiling the code? If yes, then you may haven't noticed that there are lot of issues in the code.

1. In here "int tempabc = abc;" you are trying to access the variable in another method, which is not visible outside of the method it was declared
2. The same above incident is here "int tempbcd = bcd;"

3.The answer to your question is, you cannot access a non static method from a static method. Add the access specifier static to the method you need to access from the main.